# In flutter, how to fetch single field from api data

Tags: flutter, api

I am trying to fetch a single field from API with flutter. but I am unable to get it.
Please guide me on how to do it.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Data loaded successfully",
    "data": {
        "banner": "",
        "logo": "https://ik.imagekit.io/zoyimg//uploads/mkt/leads/logo/TXBp5pJ4Bu7MfKHrCBDvAR0X5dPRbEDrujrwUpxG.jpg",
        "digital_contract": "",
        "price_sheet": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code, where is your request ?

Comment: Consider mark answers as accepted if they helped you. Currently, you have 2 questions and 0 accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a solution with null safety
As,
logo = json['logo'] ?? 0;